# access DOM and change element font and colour

Tags: javascript, dom

[image]

I want to access some character from string and change the style of them 
for example "hello"
i want to change "h" character's color and font 
how can i do this 
i try this

```
var txt=document.getElementById('d1').getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
            txt.innerHTML="H"
            txt.style.color="red"
```

Comment: Can't get. Do you want first character of the string and change its color and font ?

Comment: yes finnaly i do it  this is my code https://codepen.io/ECMA262/pen/QRVrZK

Comment: and is there a another way for do this effect?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('di') selects a single element from the dom.

You don't need .getElementsByTagName('p')[0] after that.

The solution depends on the dom. If you have an element like 
`<span id='d1'>H</span>`, then the following is correct

```
var txt = document.getElementById('d1');
txt.innerHTML="H";
txt.style.color="red";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want first character of the string and change its color and font (which i am getting from your question), you can do something like :

```
var text_array = document.getElementById('d1').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent.split("");
text_array[0] = "<span style='color:green; font-family:Arial'>"+text_array[0]+"</span>"; 
document.getElementById('d1').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHtml = text_array.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="d1">
    <p>loading.....</p>
</div>
var txt=document.getElementById('d1').getElementsByTagName('p')[0]          var edit=txt.innerHTML//ocnvertobject  to string
var len=txt.innerHTML.length
var index=0 //container for scroll the string and change style each corrector
txt.innerHTML=edit[index].toUpperCase().fontsize(150).fontcolor("red")+edit.slice(index+1,len)
++index`
i with this code edit corrector of my string